# Losing an event triggering after adding new HTML item

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener, innerhtml

Event triggering is lost after adding new element in container.
Example code is below. Event is lost after uncomment last Javascript line

Do you know reason and how resolve this issue?

```js
<div class="container">
  <button class="test-item">text</button>
  <button class="test-item">text</button>
  <button class="test-item">text</button>
  <button class="test-item">text</button>
</div>
```

```js
var allItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test-item'));

allItems.forEach(function(item){
   item.addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log("Go!");
   });
});

var template = "<button class='test-item'>New button</button>";

//document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML += template;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the code which adds a new button to this:

```
var template = document.createElement("button");
template.className = "test-item";
template.innerHTML = "New Button";

document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(template);
```

Most likely what happens is when you use `+=` on the inner html of the container it completely recreates the child content. So a complete new set of buttons is created causing any previous event handlers to no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

You just lost the track of your listener. First, you define var allItems which return you an array, then for every item on that array you add a listener. But then you add more item in the last line of your code, that means now you have a complete different set of array. So none of your listener will work.

The solution is simple, make item first then add listener to it. Meaning, move your `var template` and `document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML += template;` to the very top of your code

Comment: Thanks for explanation but point is to add this element (and even more) after adding event

Comment: I believe you can not do that in javascript, you have to have item first then add listener to it. Your code executed line by line. Sure you can delay the function if that's what you want. I want to clarify, what is the point of adding item after define the listener function?

Comment: I need to add multiple elements on user demand. So on page is button "Add next element" and after clicking it new element with class `.test-item` is adding to the `.container`

Comment: If that's the case, then you can just add the functionality after button clicked. Your callback for "add next element" click would be making template, and assign listener to it.
`addelement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //here, make the template,

   //and here attach functionality you want for all the template
})`